# To which 'court' does 'courtyard' refer?

Tags: etymology, ambiguity

> [courtyard (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=courtyard&searchmode=none) 
>       1550s, from [court (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=court&allowed_in_frame=0) + [yard](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=yard&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1).

Strangely, the [OED](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.torontopubliclibrary.ca/view/Entry/43262?redirectedFrom=courtyard&) forgoes the etymology.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtyard) also is ambiguous. So please disambiguate the meaning of **court**? I know that **court** originated from [the PIE root gher-<sup>1</sup>](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#gher-1), which produced:

> Latin *cohors* (stem *cohort*‑), enclosed yard, company of soldiers, multitude.

But does **court** here refer to:

1. the original Latin meaning above? But then court + yard = enclosed yard + yard.  So **court** would be redundant; **yard** already means it.

2. a royal court?   3. or a law court?

Comment: "Court" has a dozen different meanings.  In this scenario it's probably best to consider the (archaic) meaning of a walled-in space around a residence.  The "yard", then, is the open area within that walled-in space.

Comment: Court like 'tennis court'?

Comment: This word would have entered English during the Middle English period, from the Old French;

Comment: http://www.anglo-norman.net/dict/AND-201-D6E41CF1-98A7FDAC-313A9835-78E28E57&session=SAB9627T1432761550

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary says that *court* can refer to

> (Social) Royal society.
>
> 1. The residence of a sovereign, prince, nobleman, or ether dignitary; a palace. *The noblemen visited the queen in her court.*
> 2. The collective body of persons composing the retinue of a sovereign or person high in authority; all the surroundings of a
>      sovereign in his regal state. *The queen and her court traveled to the
>      city to welcome back the soldiers.*

This is my understanding of *courtyard*, that it is the "yard" of the court, meaning a nobleman's home.

It also shows *court* and *courtyard* to be synonymous. I don't think the "enclosed yard + yard" thing should bother you: that kind of thing is common with many words in many languages.

---

Additionally, the Official English Dictionary (OED) seems to support this idea. It lists the following four main categories of definitions for *court*:

> 1. An enclosed area, a yard.
> 2. A princely residence, household, retinue.
> 3. An assembly held by the sovereign.
> 4. A court of judicature, of law, or of administration.

From the OED, the two earliest text quotations in the OED are from 1154 and 1175.

The earliest quotation (1154) is used to support this specific definition:

> A formal assembly held by the sovereign at his residence: in early
>   times, of his councillors and great lords, for purposes of
>   administration; in later times to give state receptions, audience to
>   ambassadors, and the like.

The second earliest quotation (1175) is used to support this definition:

> The place where a sovereign (or other high dignitary) resides and
>   holds state, attended by his retinue.

---

References:

- [courtyard on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/courtyard)
- [court on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/court#English)
- [courtyard on etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=courtyard)
- [court on OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/43198?rskey=6ukGya&result=1#eid)

Comment: Certainly, by 1586, *courtyard* had no "royal" association attached. [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=OwphAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA193&dq=court+yard&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YxhmVd-YMYeBywPk1YKYBw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=court%20yard&f=false) shows: *"Surveyors appointed to examine assessments may with constables pass through any house, or go into any court-yard or backside thereunto belonging, twice a year, to view the windows, and persons obstructing them in their duty shall forfeit five pounds ..."*

Comment: I disagree. Look at the textual examples from the OED for all of the various definitions under the category of definitions "a princely residence, household, retinue". They have corresponding quotations for the 12th century through the 19th century. The meaning is still there. There is also still a queen in Britain. The uses of the words may have been adapted to peasantry... it's a word after all. But, the question was about etymology, or the history and origin, of the word.

Comment: Additionally, I think the vernacular of the royals would have a heavy sway over the vernacular of everyone else, especially because of the lack of means of publication outside of the nobles. In other words, all new words and phrases would be influenced by the worldview of the nobility and probably would come directly from the nobility.

Comment: Joseph: don't look at the royal residence definition then.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the proper thing to do is to look at the definitions of *court* in the OED, and figure out which meanings were used in the 1550's and were also relevant to the word *courtyard*. Doing this yields (first usage 1297, and still in use in 1598):

> 2a. A large building or set of buildings standing in a court-yard; a large house or castle. In early times applied to a manorial house; *Obs.*
>   2b. Often in proper names of English manor-houses, e.g. *Hampton Court, Tottenham Court.*

So in the 16th century, a *court* (among other meanings) was a building or group of buildings in a courtyard, and a *courtyard* was the yard surrounding this court.

Comment: If you look at the definitions of "court" in the OED, I think you would come to different conclusions. There are 17 sub-entries and probably more than 40 sub-sub-entries. Only one sub-sub-entry (2a) mentions a "set of buildings". Two of the sub-sub-entries refers specifically to "a building".

Comment: @Joseph: I did look at them, and that was the conclusion I came to. Note that many of these sub-entries only became current after the word *courtyard* was coined.

Comment: There are actually very few sub-entries that have their first quotation dated after 1520. Most sub-entries pre-date "courtyard".